# Elm Port doesn't run

Tags: elm

I'm trying to fetch a json from an url and parse it in elm, following the [Reactivity tutorial](http://elm-lang.org/guide/reactivity). But for some reason my code doesn't do anything. I'm using Debug.watch to see if anything happens.

I have the following code:

```
emailUrl : String
emailUrl = some url

port fetchEmails : Task Http.Error ()
port fetchEmails =
  Http.getString (Debug.watch "url" emailUrl) `andThen` parseEmails

parseEmails : String -> Task x ()
parseEmails json =
  let result = Json.Decode.decodeString Static.emailDecoder json
  in case result of
    ...
```

The code compiles, but doesn't seem to do anything. I'm very new to elm, so I'm a bit stuck here. How should this work?

Edit: turns out it was working, but as the answer stated the Debug.watch does not work with ports yet. I was also getting a 'cross-origin request blocked', which explains why it couldn't get the json.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the decoder works correctly (they are fiddly) - do you want to share that code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elm time traveling debugger does not play well with ports yet. 
Please use `Debug.log` and check you JavaScript Console.

Comment: Aha! I tried this, and now it does show that the function is being called! I'm however also getting a "cross-origin request blocked", which explains why it's not working. Stupid I didn't think to check out the console before... Thanks!